# How do I ask Selenium IDE to check a HTTP Status Code (e.g. 2XX, 404, 500)

Tags: selenium-ide

How do I ask Selenium IDE to test HTTP Status codes after loading a page?  I know this is possible (but awkward) in regular Selenium, how about in Selenium-IDE?  Is there a plugin or other way to get something like:

```
open http://www.example.com/changepassword/obama
assertHTTPStatus 5XX
```

Thus asserting either success (or this this case failure) or a particular open?  Without checking the status code, I have to check page text, which is fragile as someone might redesign the look or feel of the error page.

There are a number of existing Stack questions that touch on this topic without addressing it head on:

- [Selenium IDE - always fail on any 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228700/selenium-ide-always-fail-on-any-500-error)
- [Checking HTTP Status Code in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354827/checking-http-status-code-in-selenium)

Answer (score 6):

You can't.  The Selenium developers made a conscious decision not to include this data at the Webdriver level.  See [webdriver Bug #141](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141) and the blog post [Rantings of a Selenium Contributor](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/07/webdriver-y-u-no-have-http-status-codes.html) which lays it out clearly:

> *Just as proponents of wanting to see HTTP status codes in the* 
>   *WebDriver API are convinced that the arguments against including it* 
>   *don't hold water, the members of the project team are equally* 
>   *convinced that adding it is a bad idea.*

If you really want to do it, you'll have to use tricks such as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228700/selenium-ide-always-fail-on-any-500-error/6989213#6989213), or pick a different tool.

Comment: Your closest workaround is to test for text on the page.  If your 500 error pages all contain the same text, you can assert that text is present.